# React/Webpack assets/bundle/app not found

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to get Reactjs working with my Django app. I've been following [this](https://github.com/mbrochh/django-reactjs-boilerplate) tutorial, and got it working locally. However when I committed my branch, then pulled to the remote server, it is no longer working. The Django server and the node script for hot-reloading work fine with no errors, but when I visit the webpage none of the react components are loaded [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNcPt.png)

You can see the file structure I get in my browser when running it [locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10fl2.png).

I'm at a bit of a loss, as I've done everything the same way on the server as when I set it up locally. Here is the contents of my package.json:
`{
  "name": "ultimate_transport",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.0.93",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.5.1",
    "radium": "^0.16.6",
    "react-cookie": "^0.4.5",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.3"
  }
}`

I'm new to react, and to be honest have found npm to be a nightmare. Just don't know how to use it properly I guess. Anyway if anyone has an idea, I'd really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: You say it doesn't work on remote server. The screenshot errors show localhost. Make sure your urls are correct for remote.

Comment: The first screenshot is from it running on the server. The other tab has it running locally, and the terminal at the bottom is the local version.

URLs are fine for the server, as I have other web-pages (that don't use react) that I can load without errors.

Comment: Why don't you name your bundle?